# Will OTA (Over-the-Air) updates download when tethered?

Tags: ios, wifi, bluetooth, software-update, tethering

I have a wifi-only iPad, and I understood (or, have heard) it will automatically download iOS system updates when connected to wifi.

Will iOS automatically download an OTA ([Over-the-Air](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/09/19/updating-to-ios-6-using-over-the-air-update/)) update when it is tethered to an iPhone (via iPhone wifi or bluetooth)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can download the update while tethered to the iPhone via WiFi.  But to clarify, it won't ever automatically download the update without user intervention.

[This article from OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2013/03/04/get-around-the-50mb-download-limit-for-apps-on-an-iphone/) details some further workarounds to this issue.

Comment: That is correct. The iPad cannot distinguish its connection to your iPhone's Personal Hotspot from a connection to any other standard WiFi network.